# Obter valores do dentro de stdClass array stdClass

Tags: php, array, wsdl, stdclass

Tenho essa classe onde que eu consigo fazer a consulta e retornar dados de um webservice externos:

```
$params = array(
    'usuario' => $usuario,
    'senha' => $senha,
    'quantidade' => 2
);

$wsdl = 'http://xxxx.com?WSDL';

$options = array(
        'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
        'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'connection_timeout'=>15,
        'trace'=>true,
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
        'exceptions'=>true,
    );
try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);        
    $data = $soap->obterDados($params);     
}
    catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Porém o resultado que o `var_dump($data)` me retorna é algo assim:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["return"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (26) {
      ["idVeiculo"]=>
      int(123456)
      ["placa"]=>
      string(9) "ABC2222-2"      
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (26) {
      ["idVeiculo"]=>
      int(123457)
      ["placa"]=>
      string(9) "ABC1111-2"      
    }
  }
}
```

Eu preciso pegar os dados `["idVeiculo"]` e `["placa"]`, porém os casos exemplificados não contém a estrutura com 2 objetos `stdClass` e um array `return`.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

***EDIT***

Adicionei o código abaixo ao original e consegui visualizar as placas. 
Existe uma forma menos paleativa que essa?

```
$xml = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);

echo $xml["return"][0]["placa"];
echo $xml["return"][1]["placa"];
```

Comment: tenta isso aqui:
foreach($data->return as $veiculo){
    echo $veiculo->placa;
}

Comment: @DerleiLisboa isso mesmo. Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: depois eu elaboro uma resposta completa e posto como resposta, para seguirmos o padrão do site que não recomenda respostas nos comentários.

Comment: Demorou um pouco mais publiquei a resposta ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo seu exemplo temos a seguinte estrutura:

O objeto `$data` onde o mesmo tem um atributo chamado `return` que é um array de objetos. Para acessar o atributo `return` utilizamos `$data->return`.

Pelo fato do `return` ser um array podemos percorre-lo dinamicamente utilizando o `foreach($data->return, $veiculo)` onde o primeiro parâmetro é o array a ser percorrido(no nosso caso o `$data->return`) e o segundo é o elemento retornado em cada iteração(Damos a este parâmetro o nome que queremos, neste caso achei conveniente dar o nome de `$veiculo` pois a cada iteração ele retornara um objeto com dados de veículos).

Baseado na explicação acima o código para solucionar o seu problema é o seguinte:

```
foreach ($data->return as $veiculo) { 
    echo $veiculo->placa; 
}
```

Comment: Excelente explicação. Funcionou perfeitamente. E caso eu tenha uma lista de objetos _Eventos_ dentro de `$veiculo` é só fazer `foreach($veiculo->evento as $evento){ echo $evento->codigo; }` dentro do foreach anterior, correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo, dentro de cada iteração do `foreach` anterior você poderá percorrer esse array `$veiculo->evento`, e manipular os seus dados conforme sua necessidade.